# perform Image cropping on Image like data using Python

Tags: python, image, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy

I have image-like data. And I wont to perform Image cropping, squishing and zooming, on one or both axis. The problem is that the data is not in between 0-255, and normalizing it to 0-255, would mean loosing a lot of the information I want to preserve. So unfortunately I can’t use `PIL` or `cv2`. Is there a easy way to do it with `numpy` or `scipy`?

Thanks for the help

Comment: What is the type and range of the data then please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can crop pictures with simple indexing, like

```
picture[100:300, 400:800]
```

To squish or zoom (is that anything more than resizing?), you can just `resize` with `skimage`:

```
from skimage import data, color
from skimage.transform import resize 

image = color.rgb2gray(data.astronaut())

image_resized = resize(image, (image.shape[0] // 4, image.shape[1] // 4),
                       anti_aliasing=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check ImageChops function of Image Librart